# Pico W submodules issue

Tags: windows, pi-pico-w

### Problem

I'm pretty new to Raspberry Pi Pico. I am using Windows 10.

I installed all neccesary stuff (Visual Studio Code, CMake, compiller, etc.) using executable from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-setup-windows).

I buit example projects from there, but there was no `pico_w` folder.

I went to https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples and download all example projects, inclunding `pico_w` and just replaced with my current `pico-examples` folder.

I also did the same for SDK (download folder from [GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk) and replace current one with it).

Then I restarted VS Code, switched to "Cmake" extension tab, pressed "Configure All Projects", however there was no `pico_w` element in the list, although in "Explorer" tab, of the project folder, of course it was.

Then I copied `pico_w\wifi\access_point` folder to `hello_world`, just near `serial` and `usb` folders.

After that, it started to be displayed at CMake list, however can't be compiled, becuause it can't find most of include header, such as `pico/cyw43_arch.h`, `lwip/pbuf.h`, `dhcpserver.h`.

Project without that headers sucessfully complies.

Current CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# initialize the SDK directly
include("C:/Program Files/Raspberry Pi/Pico SDK v1.5.1/pico-sdk/pico_sdk_init.cmake")

project(pico_examples C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if (PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS "1.3.0")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Raspberry Pi Pico SDK version 1.3.0 (or later) required. Your version is ${PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING}")
endif()


# initialize the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

include(example_auto_set_url.cmake)

add_compile_options(-Wall
        -Wno-format          # int != int32_t as far as the compiler is concerned because gcc has int32_t as long int
        -Wno-unused-function # we have some for the docs that aren't called
        )
if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    add_compile_options(-Wno-maybe-uninitialized)
endif()

set(PICO_BOARD pico_w)

# rest of your project
add_subdirectory(pico_w)


add_executable(wifi
    pico_w/wifi/access_point/picow_access_point.c
)

# Add pico_stdlib library which aggregates commonly used features
target_link_libraries(wifi pico_stdlib
pico_cyw43_arch_lwip_poll # we need Wifi to access the GPIO, but we don't need anything else
hardware_flash
hardware_irq
hardware_adc
hardware_pwm
hardware_i2c
hardware_spi
hardware_dma
hardware_exception)

# create map/bin/hex/uf2 file in addition to ELF.
pico_add_extra_outputs(wifi)
```

Current project tree

```
pico_w -> wifi -> access_point    -> dhcpserver -> ...
|       |        |                -> dnsserver -> ...
|       |        |                -> CMakeLists.txt
|       |        |                -> lwipopts.txt
|       |        |                -> picow_access_point.c
|       |        -> CMakeLists.txt
|       |        -> lwipopts_examples_common.h
|        -> CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt (content above)
exemaple_auto_set_url.cmake
```

Content of `wifi` folder just from GitHub.
Also there is `.vscode` folder, with `setting.json` where I put:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "dhcpserver.h": "c"
    },
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "PICO_BOARD": "pico_w",
        "TARGET": "access_point",
        "DPICO_CYW43_SUPPORTED": 1
    }
}
```

### Research

Seems, like "submodules" are not initizalied:

```
[cmake]   cyw43-driver submodule has not been initialized; Pico W 
wireless support will be unavailable
[cmake]   hint: try 'git submodule update --init' from your SDK directory
```

I tried to call `git submodule update --init` from cmd, that comes from installation executable, but after two seconds it just returned empty newline.

`.gitmodules` content:

```
 [submodule "tinyusb"]
 path = lib/tinyusb
 url = https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb.git
 [submodule "lib/cyw43-driver"]
 path = lib/cyw43-driver
 url = https://github.com/georgerobotics/cyw43-driver.git
 [submodule "lib/lwip"]
 path = lib/lwip
 url = https://github.com/lwip-tcpip/lwip.git
 [submodule "lib/mbedtls"]
 path = lib/mbedtls
 url = https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls.git
 [submodule "lib/btstack"]
 path = lib/btstack
 url = https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack.git
```

In 'lib' folders of sdk there was folders of submodels with corresponding names, yet they was empty. So I just followed each link, download zips and exctract them to the folders.

After that, cmake warnings disapeared, as well as "header not found" errors in the `picow_access_point.c`, but I still can't compile, because:

```
[build] C:/Program Files/Raspberry Pi/Pico SDK v1.5.1/pico- 
sdk/lib/lwip/src/include/lwip/opt.h:51:10: fatal error: lwipopts.h: No such file or directory
[build]    51 | #include "lwipopts.h"
```

Also, when I set my `wifi` executable as build target (that initially is `ALL`), instead of `picow_access_point_poll` or `picow_access_point_background`(that come from examples), then there appears one error in code `picow_access_point.c`, that `pico/cyw43_arch.h` not found.

### "Solution"

Just found out, that if I set `picow_access_point_poll` or `picow_access_point_background` as target, then it builds.